# Display the two first posts which have the tag 'Rails'

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I'm using tags for my Jekyll posts. The following code shows if a post with the tag 'Rails' is present.

```
{% assign has_ruby_on_rails_posts = false %}
{% for post in site.posts %}
  {% if has_ruby_on_rails_posts == false and post.tags contains 'Rails' %}
    {% assign has_ruby_on_rails_posts = true %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% if has_ruby_on_rails_posts %}
  Rails Post is present
{% endif %}
```

I would like to display the first two posts which have the tag 'Rails' but I can't figure out how to assign them to a separate array. Is there a way to just display the first two posts which have the tag 'Rails'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [for limit](http://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/tags/iteration-tags#for) to the rescue !

```
{% assign posts = site.tags.Rails %}
{% for post in posts limit:2 %}
  {{ post.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I can figure out why it doesn't work. Can you show one post code ?

Comment: I removed my comment, but, yes, it's case sensitive.